# Windows Form Application and SQL Server Hosted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms

If our sql database was hosted externally on an sql server website and we were connecting to it via a windows desktop application, how to get around the issue, if the internet was not working.

Is there a way to keep the data local so the application still works, and replicate the changes to the sql server once the internet is connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the data localy when the internet is down, you will need a local database. You can replicate the data between the 2 databases